# Android: How to add data to an empty listView

Tags: android

I have a problem with listView, I used ArrayList to store data, and a customized Adapter. But, when I remove all the data, and add one item again, it does not display anything in this list. What happens to my List, can anyone help me?

```
static ArrayList<String>  chattingListData=new ArrayList<String>(); 
static IconicAdapter chattingListDataAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

   super.onCreate(icicle);
   chattingListDataAdapter=new IconicAdapter(this);
   setListAdapter(chattingListDataAdapter);
   registerForContextMenu(this.getListView());

}

class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

   Activity context;

   IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
      super(context, R.layout.chatting_list, chattingListData);       
      this.context=context;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatting_list, null);
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.chattinglist_userName);
      label.setText(chattingListData.get(position));  
      return(row);
   }
}
```

I use static ArrayList to modify data from outside, when I start the ListView activity and add data, it's Ok, but when I remove all data, I can not add anymore to the data list. Please help me.

Comment: please show us the code where you are changing the list

Answer (score 2):

> I use static ArrayList to modify data from outside

Don't do that.

Step #1: Use a non-static `ArrayList` data member as the basis for your `ArrayAdapter`.

Step #2: Expose methods on your activity that adds and removes items via the `add()`, `insert()`, and `remove()` methods on `ArrayAdapter`. By using these methods, your `ListView` will automatically update when you make the changes.

Step #3: Use the methods you wrote in Step #2 to modify the contents of your `ListView`, by whoever is doing this (not shown in your code).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() method, in order to force it to refresh.